# exporting String into a file without interpretating `${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}`

Tags: javascript

I want to transform a text to a JSON objet without interpretating the value of ${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV} ...

Here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');

const env = `let cfg = \`${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}\``;

fs.writeFile(pathEnv, env, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    return console.log('Config file written successfully!');
});
```

the issue with that i m getting

```
let cfg = `undefined`;
```

I want to get

```
let cfg = `${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}`;
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution :

```
const env = `let cfg = \`\${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}\``;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must either use single quotes or double quotes in your string like this:

```
const env = "let cfg = '${process.env.REACT_APP_ENV}'";
```

That will make it a string!